# JK-Flip Flop: K-Map to find the Value of Next State (Qn+1)

Tags: flip-flop, digital-design

Given the Truth Table, Characteristic Table and Excitation table for a JK Flip Flop. I am doing a K-Map to find Qn+1 (next state) given J, K and current State. The K-Map from a tutorial explaining this is shown below:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/73irC.png]

Why isn't JK' (not K) not included in the equation for Qn+1 ? Why is Qn+1 = QnK'+JQn **when there is a grouping of two 1's in the right most corner  which equals JK'**

Answer (score 1):

There should be atleast one non-overlapping cell in every group we are considering.

In your situation, JK' cannot be considered as both the cells is already present in 2 other groups and there is no non-overlapping  cells.

Hence there is no point in considering JK'